# CodeIgniter zip archive with exclude a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create full site backup but i want to exclude a folder from archive.

**My directory:**

```
/application/
/backups/      >>> I dont want to archive this folder because of nested archiving.
/themes/
/uploads/
.htaccess
index.php
```

**Tried following codes:**

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$this->zip->read_dir(FCPATH);
$this->zip->archive(FCPATH.'backups/'.date('Y-m-d-His').'.zip');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can workout something like this, in which you will never have to manually enter the new directory you create

```
$this->load->library('zip');

$data = array_diff(scandir(FCPATH), array('..', '.','backups'));
// 'backups' folder will be excluded here with '.' and '..'

foreach($data as $d) {

    $path = FCPATH.$d;

    if(is_dir($path))
        $this->zip->read_dir($path, false);

    if(is_file($path))
        $this->zip->read_file($path, false);
}

$this->zip->archive(FCPATH.'backups/'.date('Y-m-d-His').'.zip');
```

Comment: Then it looks automated. No need to re-coding if new folder created :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little manual that `setting each root directories and files` like following:

```
$this->load->library('zip');

// Choose directory and files
$this->zip->read_dir(FCPATH.'application', false);
$this->zip->read_dir(FCPATH.'themes', false);
$this->zip->read_dir(FCPATH.'uploads', false);
$this->zip->read_file(FCPATH.'.htaccess', false);
$this->zip->read_file(FCPATH.'index.php', false);

$this->zip->archive(FCPATH.'backups/'.date('Y-m-d-His').'.zip');
```

*Tested on CodeIgniter 3.x and Wamp Server*